# how to update McAfee through command line

Tags: command-line, anti-virus

I have McAfee Total Protection anti-virus installed on my computer and would like to commit an update through command line.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to find mcupdate.exe file in McAfee directory and run:

```
mcupdate /update /quiet
```

Comment: Wow, and why did i get -1? Any comments?